# Razor foreach vs Jquery .each to display table, which is better?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Lets suppose you have to display database table data on your website and it has around 1000-4000 rows. What would you do? Use simple razor foreach:

```
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.LoadServiceList) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>@item.kvab.ToString()</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>@item.kw_demand.ToString()</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>@item.kva_demand.ToString()</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
```

Or

```
success: function (response) {
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.rank + '</td><td>' + item.content + '</td><td>' + item.UID + '</td></tr>';
        });
        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
    }
```

With no custom pagination,which one would be faster/better and why?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use server side datatable for this. It provides you:

```
Ordering on columns
Searching
Pagination
Change no of rows to be displayed
and may more...
```

And the best part is it do not have any extra overhead as it fetch the specified no. of records to show by using **LIMIT**

[Datatable Reference](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: If you do not have to use any kind of plug in which one would be better? Jquery looping or razor c# loop or would you construct the table at the serverside and pass it to the ajax method?

Answer (score 1):

If use jquery looping, page load faster.Jquery will continue to fetch dataafter the page loads.If use razor foerach page waits until the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, usually jquery is used when the user do some action inside of a form (like click on a button), Razor loop is used when you have to work with models and fill the page with the value returned. Imo if you have returned a model i would use Razor to create tables, but if you want you can use jqgrid plugin to create cool custom tables. Here's the documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php